# Can compactified dimensions enlarge and large dimensions compactify in string theory?

Tags: cosmology, string-theory, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, compactification

In string theory, can six or more dimensions rolled up into high-dimensional compact manifold become large and our 3+1 large dimensions collapse into compact manifold?